# Suspended from chat?

Tags: discussion, chat

How did I suspended from chatting? Can I have it removed? I have never really used chat and have done nothing to loose the privilege?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chat is not run through the specific site which it is tied to, but rather through the main Stack Exchange chat. According to what I can see, you were suspended from chat on 15 February of this year for 358 days (seems arbitrary, but that's what it says). Your suspension will last until 7 February 2018. I don't know the reason for your suspension, what site you were suspended from in the first place, or who suspended you, but I'd presume you might have an inkling of the who/what/when/where/why of it all. In the meantime, there's nothing any of the mods of Mech can do for you but to allow the suspension to run its course. I apologize for that, but really there's nothing we can do. For your edification, this was not the first suspension listed for chat, but I'll not go into detail and air dirty laundry.

Comment: To many low quality contributions

Comment: @Muze - Yah, sorry about that. Nothing really to do with Mech, I realize, but someone felt there was an issue. We as mods are not really supposed to second guess what other mods do or why they do it. Can you tell me which site?

Comment: It was physics.

Comment: Tired of getting suspended for years at a time by them.

Comment: It would be nice for them to say to me if you make one more mistake we'll mess you up across the entire SE. I would have.been more careful.